# Responsive alignment of multiple images (horizontal AND vertical axis)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I think this gif explains it very well:

https://gfycat.com/FormalReasonableHagfish

Context: I'm working on a digital catalog (I didn't start the project) for a company that sells TONS of products, sometimes they are small, sometimes big, sometimes wide, etc. They go on a specific area, lets say 400px x 400px.

I did horizontal alignment with flexbox and it works very well but on the vertical axis the products have static values (prod_1 top: 0px, prod_2: top 10px, prod_3 top: 20px...)

---

**EDIT: My question/need is: I want to be able to align (responsively in the horizontal and vertical axis) 1 to 6 images inside 1 div but flexbox only let me choose one axis (flex-direction row or column), what can I do?**

**The code is something like this:**

```
<div class='container'>
  <img class='item_0'>
  <img class='item_1'>
  <img class='item_2'>
  <img class='item_3'>
  <img class='item_4'>
</div>
```

**If posible the solution should be in CSS, if it can't be done, then it could be in Javascript or maybe changing a little bit the HTML.**

**This is because I only have access to CSS and JS. The index.html is generated automatically from a database by an application developed/controlled by another team and it's not that easy/quick to ask them for changes.**

---

The best way I thought is with javascript but it may not be that easy, considering it's a big project and there's A LOT of code already written (not by me).

What do you guys think? I don't need the complete solution but some direction would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I've been trying, and this is the closest I did with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/er3b99nd/15/ (only 3 items though)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am not 100% sure about what you need, but here's some code I made that does pretty much what your gif showed. You should be able to tweak it to your liking.

[image: Flexbox rows and columns]

https://codepen.io/AlexWulkan/pen/wmmPvL

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Outer container */
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

/* Each row of boxes */
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

/* determines the position of the boxes in each row */
.row:first-child {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row:nth-child(2) {
    justify-content: center;
}

.row:last-child {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

/* Each box */
.box {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Tell me if there's anything you have questions about and I'll try to answer. The code should be quite self-explanatory though. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution it's similar to the one I posted in my comment (below my question). It doesn't work quite well because it needs to work with 1 to 6 products. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it well, I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: So you want to diagonally align 1-6 items from the top right to the bottom left? If there's only one item should it be centered?

Does everything need to have exactly that html structure as you showed in your edited post? If you need different alignments based on the amount of items, then I think it needs to be done with JS.

Comment: Yes to all of your questions. Not everything need to have exactly that html structure, but I think it can't change THAT much. Yeah I thought that too, JS is the way, right? Thank you for your time Alex!

Comment: Yes, JS is the way. You would have to select the parent div, count how many children it has, calculate the horizontal position each one of them should have, then assign the appropriate styling to each of them. Good luck. :)

Comment: It's not responsive, though. If you add `max-width:400px;width:100%` to the `.container` then it will shrink in smaller screens instead of scrolling.

Comment: @PossessWithin I only added it because he said "They go on a specific area, lets say 400px x 400px.". But yes, you need to remove the fixed values for it to be fully responsive.